# How to remove the memory limit of a Windows Job Object?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have configured a memory limit for my process using Job Objects. Now I'd like to remove that limit. I assume I have to set `JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION.ProcessMemoryLimit` to a specific value and call `SetInformationJobObject`. What value should I use? [It's undocumented.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684156(v=vs.85).aspx)

Since changing the process job assignment seems problematic simply breaking away from the job is not possible (at least on Windows 7).

For context here's some C# code that I am using but it seems immaterial to the question:

```
var limitInfo = new NativeMethods.JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION()
{
    BasicLimitInformation = new NativeMethods.JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION()
    {
        LimitFlags = NativeMethods.LimitFlags.JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY,
    },
    ProcessMemoryLimit = (UIntPtr)maxProcessMemoryBytes,
};

if (!NativeMethods.SetInformationJobObject(jobHandle, NativeMethods.JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS.JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, (IntPtr)(&limitInfo), (uint)structSize))
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

`0` seems to be rejected by the OS and `-1` results in this:

[image]

`-4KB` as a limit. There's insufficient validation apparently.

Comment: `I have configured a memory limit for my process` - how you configured - exactly this way and *change* limit, instead *remove*

Comment: @RbMm not sure what you are saying. I want the limit to exist but only for some time. I can't simply not set any limit if that's what you mean.

Comment: but you set limit or no ?

Comment: Yes I do and that's intentional.

Comment: so, do this again when you want *remove* limit. but intead simply change to maximum value

Comment: That's my plan but I'm asking what's the proper value to set. I could just the the maximum integer but that seems dirty and maybe it has performance consequences.

Comment: think `MAXINT_PTR` or `MAXSSIZE_T` (this is the same values)

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to just remove `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY` flag?

Comment: @zett42 I tested that and it works. Thanks! Want to make an answer? If not I'll self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First call [`QueryInformationJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms684925(v=vs.85).aspx) to obtain the current limits and flags, remove the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY` flag from [`JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION::BasicLimitInformation::LimitFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684147(v=vs.85).aspx) and finally call [`SetInformationJobObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms686216(v=vs.85).aspx) with this data to remove the process memory limit.